# matplotlib xtick labels are not aligned properly

Tags: python, matplotlib, time-series, axis-labels

I found a strange symptom while making a time-series monitoring logic with matplotlib.

Have you ever seen a similar symptom like the below image ?

The xlabels in the blue box are not aligned properly.

[image]

Here I'm copying used code related with labeling.

Any comments or information to solve this problem will be appreciated!

```
def build_xlabelstr(index):
    hour = 9
    min = 0

    hour += index / 60
    res = index % 60
    min += res

    str = "%d:%02d"%(hour, min)

    return str

major_xticks = np.arange(0, len(df.close), 15)
minor_xticks = np.arange(0, len(df.close), 5)
major_xlabels = [build_xlabelstr(i) for i in major_xticks]
minor_xlabels = [build_xlabelstr(i) if (i % 3) > 0 else "" for i in minor_xticks]

axis.tick_params(axis = 'both', which = 'major', labelsize = 9)
axis.tick_params(axis = 'both', which = 'minor', labelsize = 0)
axis.set_xticks(major_xticks)
axis.set_xticks(minor_xticks, minor=True)
axis.tick_params(which='both', direction='out')
```

Comment: can you turn this into a complete example? there are lots of undefined variable and namespaces in the code that you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Comment out the line

```
axis.tick_params(which='both', direction='out')
```

It seems that you need to find a different way of offsetting your labels.